# Salvar valor de tabela

Tags: array, lua

Eu gostaria de salvar o valor atribuido á uma tabela em tempo real, vou explicar.

Tenho 2 arquivos:

***Main.lua***

```
dofile("tester.lua")

io.write("blabla")

table.insert(oi, io.read())

print(oi[1])

io.read()
```

---

***tester.lua***

```
oi = {}
```

Se eu executar e escrever: kkk
retornará -> kkk
Mas ao fechar o programa, não salva no arquivo. Como faço pra que o valor adicionado a tabela continue salvo?

Comment: Estou executando em modo prompt.
Ele pega o que o usuário digitar.

Comment: Minha pergunta foi meio idiota... Eu que fui burro... Me concentrar em mais de uma coisa ao mesmo tempo não tá dando muito certo... =/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode ser interessante abrir o arquivo em uma variável e editar o arquivo por ela no final da execução:

```
dofile("tester.lua")
arquivo = assert(io.open("tester.lua", "w"), "Falha ao abrir arquivo") -- O assert é apenas caso possa dar algum erro, mas caso prefira, descomente a linha abaixo e comente essa!
--arquivo = io.open("tester.lua", "w")
io.write("blabla")
table.insert(oi, io.read())
print(oi[#oi])

texto = "oi = {"
for i = 1, #oi do
    texto = texto.."\""..tostring(oi[i]).."\""
    if not (i == #oi) then
        texto = texto..", "
    end
end
texto = texto.."}"

arquivo:write(texto)
arquivo:flush()
io.close(arquivo)
io.read()
```

Desta forma, ele vai inserindo na tabela os dados que forem passados no prompt.

Comment: Gammeth, acho que vocÊ não entendeu, eu quero adicionar um valor á tabela criada em 'tester.lua' e mante-lo lá.
De qualquer forma, obrigado.

Comment: @GabrielSales acho que comecei a entender seu problema, mas pra ter certeza do que devo responder, me responda: No caso, você pretende adicionar vários valores na tabela, e cada vez que executar ele acrescenta mais um arquivo, correto?

Comment: Quase isso, mas não adiciona mais um arquivo, apenas salva o valor no arquivo tester.lua, dentro da tabela.

Comment: @GabrielSales alterei a minha resposta. É desta forma que você quer?

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado.
Era exatamente isso.